# Вопрос по заданию - выведите все числа между заданными двумя

Tags: c++

Есть задание в практикуме: выведите все числа между заданными двумя. Но теперь первое число может быть больше второго. В таком случае выводить числа нужно в обратном порядке.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x, y;
    cin >> x >> y;
   for (int i =x; i<=y; ++i){
cout << i << endl;
}
      for (int i=x; i>=y; --i){
cout << i << endl;
}
}
```

Вроде бы работает, но компилер ругается:
Задача прошла 21/31 проверок

Возможные проблемы:

- Вы неправильно обрабатываете случай, когда начало и конец отрезка равны

Не совсем понимаю, как обработать эту ситуацию...

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: if x ==y  наверное?

Comment: "когда начало и конец отрезка равны" - оба цикла выводят это число

Comment: Как вариант можно обернуть второй цикл в условие типа `if (x != y)` — тогда цикл не будет выполняться при равенстве, т.к. он уже выполнился ранее

Comment: разобрался, всех благодарю

Answer (score 3):

Величина `d` будет равна `1` если `x < y`, `0` если `x = y`, `-1` если `x > y`.
Тогда можно будет сделать один цикл с инкрементом `i += d`. Выход из цикла необычный чтобы можно было успеть напечатать последнее число:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int x, y;
    if (!(std::cin >> x >> y)) {
        return 1;
    }
    const int d = (x < y) - (y < x);
    for (int i = x; ; i += d){
        std::cout << i << '\n';
        if (i == y) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror range.cpp 
>
> +~/desk/stackoverflow $ echo 1 5 | ./a.out 
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 5
>
> +~/desk/stackoverflow $ echo 5 1 | ./a.out 
> 5
> 4
> 3
> 2
> 1
>
> +~/desk/stackoverflow $ echo 1 1 | ./a.out 
> 1
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы решить это задание нужно использовать блок else {}, который просто будет выполняться при несоблюдении первого условия x < y​.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]